# Could the distance between two Gaussian Distributions be defined as the Frobenius norm of their parameters?

Tags: probability

For two Gaussian distributions $ \mathcal{N}(m_1, \Sigma_1)$ and $\mathcal{N}(m_2, \Sigma_2)$. Could we define the distance as

$d[\mathcal{N}(m_1, \Sigma_1),\mathcal{N}(m_2, \Sigma_2)] = \|m_1-m_2\|^2_F + \| \Sigma_1-\Sigma_2\|^2_F $, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm?

Or more generally speaking, for any two distribution family with parameters $\{\theta^1_1,\dots \theta^n_1\}$ and $\{\theta^1_2,\dots \theta^n_2\}$ respectively, could we define the distance as $\sum^n_{i=1} \|\theta^i_1-\theta^i_2\|^2_F $  ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't define that distance if you wanted, but seem very useful to me, apart from checking to see if it is exactly 0 or not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MikaelÖhman . I think it is well-defined, but unfortunately, I do not find any paper mentioned this. So, I am wondering whether the distance is valid. Do you know any relevant material?